# EE3: Polls or surveys?

Tags: add-on, ee3

Does anyone know of any poll or survey modules that work with EE3? The ones I've checked out say - on the companies' sites - that they currently work with EE2, and not yet EE3.

Comment: sorry to inform you, there is no available plugin for polls or surveys for EE3. You can covert one in EE3 if you have some module development knowledge.

Comment: I don't have any module development knowledge. That was one of the things that I liked about EE: a pretty robust group of plugins. Things seem like they're dying out now. Well, looks like I'll have to go with third-party/embedded for this for my site, then. Thankfully there are options...

Answer (score 0):

As I'm also researching such add-on possibilities so far I found:

1. DevDaemon Channel Polls[Channel Polls](https://eeharbor.com/polls/documentation/getting_started)
2. EE Harbour Polls (acquired from Solspace I think) [Polls](https://eeharbor.com/polls/documentation/getting_started)
   accuired  [1](https://eeharbor.com/polls/documentation/getting_started): http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/channel-polls
3. [VWM Polls](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vwm-polls) - a free one from depot:ee

I found these, but I think for my purpose I need also a custom development as they are giving you pretty basic and standard options as most of the polls on the market

Comment: I'm using Channel Polls, to display the results and having more options the Channel Fields entries are converted to JSON, CSV or XML and imported in many JavaScript charts ( I'm using Higcharts). So many more options are available.

Comment: I think all of them deliver you basic poll functionality. If you want to go crazy - either you should extend some of them, create your own or go for external solution.

Comment: Yes you're right, but add-on like Channel Polls have a questions system with data statistics. It'very well integrated to EE, I didn't have time to develop a such own solution. In 15 min, I linked Channel Polls to Higcharts, results: it's very powerful and fast to implement! No need  to reinvent the wheel , if your time delay is short.